# Program efficiency, allocate memory for both read and write

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-efficient

I wrote a simple program and I would like to know if I wrote that program in a efficient way. The program opens a file for reading and writing and then write with `pwrite`(I don't want the offset of the file to move with the writing), and reading the file with `pread`. I am just curious to know if it is necessary to allocate memory twice as I do.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *write_buf = malloc(14), *read_buf = malloc(14);

    int fd = open("file", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644); /* open a file called file */
    if (fd == -1) {
         perror("write");
         exit(-1); // Error, exit program
    }

    strcpy(write_buf, "Hello, World!"); /* copy string into write_buf */
    pwrite(fd, write_buf, strlen(write_buf), 0); /* pwrite (without moving file pointer) write_buf into fd (file) */
    pread(fd, read_buf, strlen(write_buf), 0); /* pread (without moving file pointer) into read_buf from fd (file) */

    close(fd);
    free(write_buf); free(read_buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not it's not necessary. You can read into the same buffer than the one you wrote.

Comment: Tip: Don't stack your definitions like this, it just creates confusion. Each `char *x = malloc()` should be on its own line. Additionally, `14` should be a defined constant somewhere, not just slapped in there arbitrarily.

Comment: Tip: Don't use `strcpy()`, use `strncpy()` and be *sure* the buffer has enough room for your strings. In C it's very important to *test return values* to detect errors. You're hardly doing any of that here. `"Hello, World!"` *just* fits in that buffer. If you added another `!` you have a buffer-overflow bug, so this approach is teetering on the edge of disaster.

Comment: @Jabberwocky But I need to clear it first, no?

Comment: If you `pread` into something trust me it will *get* cleared.

Comment: @HassanNasrallah actually you need to clear it, because otherwise you won't see any difference, because you're reading the same content you just wrote. But reading the thing you just wrote is pretty pointless anyway.

Comment: You know that you can just write the string to the file, without moving it to a buffer? Something like `const char input[]="Hallo World!"; ssize  r=pwrite(fd,input,strlen(input),0);` should work fine.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Yes, I know.

Comment: Do you know that `strlen()` can eat up most of the time when the string gets long? If you want to be efficent, use `sizeof` or store the size somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going just a little bit wrong here, but in C a little bit wrong is the difference between works fine and crashes all the time. Cleaning it up results in this:

```c
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
  char *buf = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);

  int fd = open("file", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644);

  if (fd == -1) {
    perror("write");
    exit(-1);
  }

  // Here strncpy() can fail if the buffer is too small, so ensure
  // your buffer size is big enough for any reasonable cases. Test the
  // return value if you're not sure what the input size is going to be.
  strncpy(buf, "Hello, World!", BUFFER_SIZE);
  pwrite(fd, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
  
  // strlen() is the wrong tool here, you need the size of the buffer
  // itself, not the length of whatever's in it.
  pread(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

  close(fd);

  // This wouldn't be necesssary if you had: char buf[BUFFER_SIZE]
  free(buf);

  return 0;
}
```

Learn the difference between `strlen()` and `sizeof`, as well as how to use constant sizes consistently through your code.

The principle here is you want to change *one thing* and have it ripple through your code correctly.

Comment: Thanks, what return values should I check?

Comment: I don't think that checking every single call is necessary

Comment: Anything that *could* return an error. In YOLO code you can get away with a lot. In other cases you can be reasonably assured that you'll never get an error, or at least not one you can deal with. In cases where you're getting unknown user data of an unknown length you must be far more careful.

Comment: You *assume* checking every single call is not necessary, and sometimes at your peril. For throw-away code like this, you can get away with a lot. If this was critical kernel code, **NO**, you **must** check.